# What is the display property of bootstrap input group?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm implementing a button that hides or display the datepick onclick.

```
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mr-5" href="../Stores/stalls.html">Check Current Operating Stalls </a>
  <div style="vertical-align: top;display:inline-block ;position:relative;border:5px solid white">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mr-5" onclick="pickTime()">Check Operating Stalls By Custom
      Time</button>

    <div class="input-group mb-3" id="datepicker" style="">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">Date</span>
      </div>
      <input id="exampleDate" class="datepicker" name="date" type="text" value="14 August, 2014"
        data-value="2014-08-08" />
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">Time</span>
      </div>
      <input id="exampleTime" class="timepicker" type="time" name="time" valuee="2:30 AM" data-value="0:00" />
    </div>
```

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOKsD.png)

But once I click the button, I can't find the right display property to restore the pattern in the image above. I've tried block/inline/inline-block. Every one of them ends up [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4bb7.png)

```
function pickTime()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("datepicker");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } 
    else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: I avoid this problem by using visibility property instead. If anyone understands the reason why this problem exists, I would be happy to know.

Comment: instead of `x.style.display = "none"` do `x.style.display = ""`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that div is a [block element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements), and the functionality you're looking after is of an inline element.

The fix is rather simple, just get your inputs inside the div's, like so:

```
<div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">Date</span>
    <input id="exampleDate" class="datepicker" name="date" type="text" value="14 August, 2014" data-value="2014-08-08" />
</div>
```

and the same for the other div